анимировать перезагруз
как можно сделать эффект обновления в этом коде?
кот работает, но при нажатие refresh нет эффекта и непонятно изменилась что-нибудь или нет
<a href="javascript://" id="recurl">refresh</a>

<div id="recomb">$COM_BODY$</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#recurl').click(function() {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999);
    $.get('$REQUEST_URI$?' + random, function(data) {
      $('#recomb').html($('#recomb', data).html());
    });
  });
</script>


а какой эффект должен был быть?

Перед запросом показать "анимированную крутилку"... После смены контента ее убрать.

мерцание например $COM_BODY$ чтобы перезагрузку подчеркнуть

добавляй класс перед вызовом get и убирай его после установки html. В классе можешь сделать любой эффект, который хочешь

вы можете мне помочь ? я не знаю как написать

https://cssloaders.github.io/ выбирай лоадер и как уже сказали перед гетом делаешь show(), после добавления html делаешь hide()

Для того чтобы увидеть эффект, его нужно добавить
для примера добавим некий css, затем в скрипте, после строчки click, добавляем наш css $('#recomb').addClass('flash');, чтоб увидеть "мерцание" на $COM_BODY$ (в конце удаляем)
Также не забудьте подключить библиотеку jQuery


$('#recurl').click(function() {
  //убираем для повторного срабатывания
  $('#recomb').removeClass('flash');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#recomb').addClass('flash'); //добавили
  }, 10);
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999);
  $.get('$REQUEST_URI$?' + random, function(data) {
    $('#recomb').html($('#recomb', data).html());
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#recomb').removeClass('flash'); //убрали
    }, 500);
  });
});
.recomb.flash {
  animation: flash 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes flash {
  50%{color:#fff;text-shadow:0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,.3),0 0 5px #f03000,0 0 8px #f80000;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript://" id="recurl">refresh</a>
<div id="recomb" class="recomb">$COM_BODY$</div>



анимации, можно выбрать тут, тут, тут
*я искала так "анимация мерцания css" (**но в тестовом окошке ru.SO не видно эффекта)

в сниппете только один раз срабатывает

@Grundy, у меня всё нормально и всё работает

@RSK, после комментария было еще 4 редакции ответа
